# Android clean application data

Tags: android

I am developing a app in which there is a button which will clear all the data (which will include files, databases, shared preferences) related with this app. any one can let me know how to clear application data by code.

Comment: You need to trigger individual cleanup calls for each of those on button click. For example Delete from tableName etc.,

Comment: I guess there is no "clearAllApplicationData()", you will have to loop thru the things the app or the user created, you know the database names, you can reset all the preferences e.g.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

call `clearApplicationData` to delete app's data:

```
/**
 * Call this method to delete any cache created by app
 * @param context context for your application
 */
public static void clearApplicationData(Context context) {
    File cache = context.getCacheDir();
    File appDir = new File(cache.getParent());
    if (appDir.exists()) {
        String[] children = appDir.list();
        for (String s : children) {
            File f = new File(appDir, s);
            if(deleteDir(f))
                Log.i(TAG, String.format("**************** DELETED -> (%s) *******************", f.getAbsolutePath()));
        }
    }
}
private static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
    if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
            if (!success) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return dir.delete();
}
```

Comment: its able to clean databases as well as files but unable to delete shared preferences.

Comment: it should delete everything in your app's cache folder. i tested it myself

Comment: can you see in logcat that what folders it deletes successfully?