# Why my app cache is not returning null even after deleting the same?

Tags: android, caching, android-networking

I am working on an app which renders a mobile website using android's web view.
My app is capable of showing the website in offline mode with the help of cache.
Upto here everything is fine.
Now i have introduced a clear cache mechanism and getting issues..

To understand the issue have a look carefully at login steps performed via login button on loginscreen(I have two buttons here **1.** Login **2.** Clear Cache):

**Step 1.** if network is *connected*, let the user enter inside app and show the online content(cache mode off)---> WORKING FINE...

**Step 2.** else if network is either *disconnected*||*suspended*||*unknown* and if cache is present, show the cached content.---WORKING FINE.

Here come the issue:

Let us suppose if there is no network and user clears/already have cleared, the cache then login then according to my logic they shouldn't be able to login but my code is failing and it login the user see this [link](http://pastebin.com/y3qZ28U5)

For clearing cache, i have done something like this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110096/android-clean-application-data)

Let me know if anyone need further clarification.

Any help will highly be appreciated.